# Where is the post box at Keflavík (Reykjavík International) airport?

Tags: airports, mail, reykjavik, kef

The [list on the postur website](http://www.postur.is/en/about-us/post-offices/post-boxes/) doesn't include specific information.

Comment: The postbox is still there (I was at the airport on May 21st 2018).

Comment: I put 3 cards in the box on the 17 th of October to go to Reykjavik and Hafnafjorð and they have not been delivered. I believe that the photo is of the box.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the red box by the "Odd size baggage" counter in the departure lounge

[image]

Comment: Still there as of Sept 3, 2018

Answer (score 4):

There is also one after security, past the duty free, in the food court area. Right behind the Nord restaurant and before heading to all gates.

[image: Post Box in departure terminal]